# How to send JSON object using RestClientHelper?

Tags: android

I need to implement login API in android. For that, I used RestClientHelper, a 3rd Party library in android https://github.com/ravi123shanker/SimpleRestClientHelper

But i need to send a json object to url like:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "username":"hello",
 "password":"1223"
}
```

From thier documentation i able to put value to postParams like :

```
{login=[{"id":1,"password":"hello","username":"1223"}]}
```

But I need to send like the above format! How could I do that:

my function is:

```
JSONArray productsJson = new JSONArray();
            try {
                JSONObject eachProduct = new JSONObject();
                eachProduct.put("fcmid", fcm_id);
                eachProduct.put("password", pin);
                eachProduct.put("username", username);
                productsJson.put(eachProduct);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Exception", "error");
            }
            ArrayMap<String, Object> postParams=new ArrayMap<>();
            postParams.put("login", productsJson.toString());
            Log.e("postParams","data "+postParams.toString());
            RestClientHelper.getInstance().post(Constants.BASE_URL_USER_LOGIN , postParams, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String error) {
                }
            });
```

Any Help, please??

Comment: What seems to be the problem here? What kind of an error are you getting? Can you post your log and the response you are getting?

Comment: @deluxe1. No error! My manager ask me to provide the json to api in that 1st given format rather than 2nd format!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to insert your JsonObject into a JsonArray and then bind it to the login parameter

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
jArray.put(productsJson);
...
postParams.put("login", jArray.toString());
```

Comment: No, in your code you binded the login parameter to the productsJson and not to the JsonArray

Comment: No! Now i get like `{login=[[{"fcmid":"sdsdsddds","password":"asasas","username":"asas"}]]}`

Comment: If so, I'm guessing that what you did was good. What is the problem? what are you getting with your original code?

Comment: I dont need that `login=` section.  just the json. I know it is coming because i given that! but how could i do that without login

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you provide an example of what you have and what you want to get?